# what version of jetty the geoserver runs?

Tags: geoserver, jetty

In order to set CORS correctly in Geoserver, I have to download some `jar` files and then edit the `web.xml` file.

I have a really old version of Geoserver(2.1.3) that runs Jetty 6.8.1 and there are no `jars` for this version, at least according to [this](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/). I was thinking to upgrading to the latest Geoserver (2.8.0). What version of Jetty does it run? Will I find the right `jars` to implement the CORS setting?

Comment: To get around the lack of jars, the following worked for me: http://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/message/32391594/

Comment: @dbaston Thanks. I tried this, but does not work for me, for reason I cannot explain

Comment: @dbaston Hey, wait. In step 1 it says `Instead, put content of this archive...into the ....folder`. How did you put it? You put just the `zip` folder as is? You unzip it? Because I dont know how to put the zip in there to make it work. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You mean GeoServer 2.1.3 runs 6.1.8 (not 6.8.1), correct?

According to [this source](https://fossies.org/linux/www/geoserver-2.8.0-bin.zip/) the included library is still Jetty 6.1.8.

Comment: Interesting. Is this official? Because, here : `http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120378/geoserver-xml-header-for-cors-xmlhttprequest` (first answer) he says that he runs Georerver v 2.6.2 .
and so he gets `jars` for Jetty v 7.6.13.v20130916 . So I guess Geoserver 2.8.0 runs higher Jetty version. Right?

Comment: Slevin -   
I just downloaded the official 2.8.0 release from geoserver.org, and inside the lib folder is jetty-6.1.8.jar. Judging from the answer in the SO link you posted, it sounded like the person had upgraded that library manually.

Comment: Thanks for testing it. As for the link, either he updated manually, or maybe he got Jetty 7 from Boundless (he says he uses Boundless). I dont know what to do, updating Geoserver now seems pointless and setting CORS on my existing Geoserver does not work

Comment: How about to run GeoServer on Tomcat?

Comment: @user30184 How do I do this? Is there a version of Geoserver that runs Tomcat instead of Jetty? Thanks

Comment: @ThomasHorner I just made the transistion to Geoserver 2.8.0. You are right, still runs Jetty 6.1.8. Anyway I will run tests with CORS and proxys on this one and let you know

Comment: Read http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/war.html. All Geoserver versions which have ever been made run also on Tomcat. The Windows installer and zipped GeoServer just installs Jetty and GeoServer  at the same time because it is a handy way for getting everything ready for the play. For real production most users run GeoServer on Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

The actual version of geoserver (v2.8.2) released on January 26, 2016 ships v6.1.8 of Jetty.

But it seems that the branch 2.9 will ship v9 of Jetty, as Justin Deoliveria [has done some work](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/commit/f61290d14872ad55cf9d30cdf00b2389f8aa76e9) on it and the related ticket [is closed](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-4239).