# reverse proxy on geoserver

Tags: geoserver, proxy, cors

I have installed the new Geoserver 2.8.0 and to avoid CORS related errors I wanted to implement a reverse proxy, instead of setting response headers.

In version 2.1.3 there was a `<filter-name>Reverse Proxy Filter</filter-name>` that you could enable, in the `web.xml` file.

In version 2.8.0, I could not found such filter. How can I implement a reverse proxy, so I can get rid of CORS related issues?

Answer (score 5):

From http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.geoserver.user/42219

1. Put content of this archive http://shanbe.hezoun.com/cors.zip into the \webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\classes folder.
2. use 
   `<filter-class>org.mortbay.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>`
   insteand of `<filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>`

You can put follwing conf. inside the \webapps\geoserver\web.xml to allow CORS requests from all domains:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.mortbay.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Restart the geoserver and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The gmane link is broken, I get `The web interface is down for maintenance.`As for your solution, you talk about a CORS filter, not a reverse proxy. Anyhow, I was looking for an official solution provided by Geoserver or Jetty. The [official CORS solution](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/cross-origin-filter.html) suggests adding servlets for Jetty7, Geoserver runs [Jetty 6](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165145/what-version-of-jetty-the-geoserver-runs)  and Jetty 7 to 8 is now [EOL](https://webtide.com/jetty-7-and-jetty-8-end-of-life/)

Comment: On Geoserver (2.8.0) I also tried unofficial things like [first answer here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120378/geoserver-xml-header-for-cors-xmlhttprequest) or [unofficial proxy](http://mapping-malaysia.blogspot.gr/2009/06/running-geoserver-with-reverse-proxy.html). I tried stupid things like copy the old proxy code from Geoserver (2.1.3) web.xml to Geoserver (2.8.0) web.xml. Also on Geoserver (2.8.0) I added `http://localhost:8080` on the `Proxy Base URL` under `Global`, `Settings` in the Geoserver (2.8.0) console. Nothing. Either a broken Geoserver, or errors or no proxy.

Comment: So all Geoserver tricks did not work, CORS filter nor proxy. Plus, I dont usually deploy unofficial solutions. So I used a reverse proxy from node, to Geoserver, with this [middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) and works just fine.

Comment: I am not too in favor of this external CORS zip file, but it's a solution. This solution also solved my need for reverse-proxy, so I might be missing your intent there.