# Jetty Version for GeoServer 2.13.0

Tags: geoserver, jetty

GeoServer 2.13.0 is running on our server and I want to add some CORS headers to it.

Which version of Jetty does it use so that I can install the correct jetty-serverlet JAR?

---

Found: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Jetty-Version-td5367079.html
Version: 9.2.13.v20150730

Note: This Jetty version is the same as Geoserver 2.10, and can be downloaded from original source or the answered Geoserver Jetty question here: [Enabling CORS in GeoServer (jetty)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/enabling-cors-in-geoserver-jetty)

Comment: Hi Ian, many thanks for flagging this as a duplicate question. My question was not about how to enable CORS headers. My question was which version of Jetty does GeoServer 2.13.0 run.

Comment: I have been searching all morning to see if I can find out which version of Jetty Geoserver is using. The closest post I have found is this one https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165145/what-version-of-jetty-the-geoserver-runs but I am still no closer to finding out which version of Jetty GeoServer 2.13.0 runs. Does anyone know where to find this?