# Add WFS layer (JSON) in Leaflet using Leaflet layer tree control

Tags: leaflet, wfs, getfeature

I'm using the layer tree control to manage the display of layers. When I add WMS services, it works fine. But when I add WFS, this is not loaded.

I'm using the Leaflet layer tree plugin code and GeoServer.

Below is the part of the code I use to add WFS layer on my main page:

```
...{ 
 "code": "space",
 "name": "space 1",
 "active": true,
 "selectedByDefault": false,
 "openByDefault": null,
 "childLayers": [],
 "selectType": null,
 "serviceType":"WFS",
 "params": {
            "request": "GetFeature",
            "service": "WFS",
            "styles":'',
            "outputformat": "application/json",
            "typeName": "rbrava:space_1",
            "url": "http://10.11.15.170:8080/geoserver/rbrava/wfs"
                      }
                    ...
```

I used the Chrome inspector and when I click on the layer checkbox to load that it gives me the following error:

`"XMLHttpRequest cannot load... 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access".`

Answer (score 1):

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Well, there's your problem. You need to [enable CORS on GeoServer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120378/geoserver-xml-header-for-cors-xmlhttprequest).

CORS is somewhat tricky, and enabling it will depend on your installation of GeoServer, and any HTTP proxies you might be running.