# Enabling CORS in GeoServer (jetty)?

Tags: geoserver, cors, jetty

I hope somebody has already figured this one out. I just installed Geoserver 2.9 on a vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 distro. The Geoserver 2.8 method of enabling CORS with the shanbe.hezoun class does no longer work with Jetty 9.2.13.

There are mentions that CORS support is already packaged with Jetty 9.2.13 in the jetty-servlets.jar.

The Jetty lib which is compiled with Geoserver contains a jetty-servlet-9.2.13.v20150730.jar in geoserver/lib but not jetty-servlets.9.2.13.v20150730.jar. Are these supposed to be the same jar with a different name?

It should be possible to enable CORS either in geoserver/etc/webdefault.xml or in geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml.

My understanding is that the webdefault.xml is applied first and the web.xml thereafter.

I have tried following filter in both xml. I haven't got as far as adding a filter mapping. Adding the filter alone will cause the Geoserver/Jetty service to not start proper.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Comment: Servlet and servlets does not seem to be the same http://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/9.2.13.v20150730/apidocs/index.html?org/eclipse/jetty/servlets. And some links to the documents you have used would help those who try to answer.

Comment: why not use tomcat?

Comment: Good question. I have Geoserver 2.9 running with Tomcat but wanted to test the binary setup just to see whether this would make my life easier. It didn't.

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: No solution. I wasn't able to enable CORS in jetty so I keep using Tomcat.

Comment: have you solved your problem? I faced the same issue with you. My geoserver was installed on Windows as a service. And I have followed this steps [from official Opengeo](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/sysadmin/cors/index.html). Adding these parameters: <filter> <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name> <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class> </filter> ... <filter-mapping> <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name> <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </filter-mapping> to /GeoServer 2.10.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml and **jetty-servlet-9.2.13.v20150730.jar** h

Comment: i am still using geoserver 2.9 running on apache. will try your comment when i get to play with a new version of geoserver. might wait for the 2.11 release.

Comment: Ok. I just already solved the problem for Geoserver 2.10. It's my fault to not installed the servlets jar correctly. I should download the correct servlets in [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/) then copy into the directory **"\WEB-INF\lib"** and edit the "**WEB-INF\web.xml**" to be add the filter parameters as I followed the comment from zflaw in this [thread](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120378/geoserver-xml-header-for-cors-xmlhttprequest?newreg=b3bb4402d6d84114ae9db05dcc9cfa0f). Jetty v9+ has already supported the CORS.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Edit the `webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml` file. There are **two** references to CORS in this file:

> ```
> <!-- Uncomment following filter to enable CORS -->
> <filter>
>   <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
>      <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
>   </filter>
> ```

and

> ```
> <!-- Uncomment following filter to enable CORS -->
> <filter-mapping>
>    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
>    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
> </filter-mapping>
> ```

You **must** uncomment **both** blocks (that is remove `<!--` and `-->` from the `filter` and `filter-mapping` blocks.

Then when you restart Jetty you can test that everything is working by using a command like:

```
curl -v -H "Origin: http://example.com" http://astun-desktop:9080/geoserver/wfs\?service\=WFS\&version\=2.0.0\&request\=GetFeature\&typenames\=sf:bugsites\&filter\=%3Cfes:Filter%20xmlns:fes\=%22http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0%22%3E%3Cfes:ResourceId%20rid\=%22bugsites.3%22/%3E%3C/fes:Filter%3E
```

which if all is well will give a result like:

```
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: astun-desktop:9080
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://example.com
>  
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com 
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true 
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers:  
< Content-Type: text/xml; subtype=gml/3.2 
< Content-Disposition: inline; filename=geoserver-GetFeature.text 
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
* Server Jetty(9.2.13.v20150730) is not blacklisted 
< Server: Jetty(9.2.13.v20150730) 
< 
* Connection #0 to host astun-desktop left intact 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sf="http://www.openplans.org/spearfish" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" numberMatched="1" numberReturned="1" timeStamp="2017-07-30T15:58:31.423Z" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://astun-desktop:9080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd http://www.openplans.org/spearfish http://astun-desktop:9080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=2.0.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=sf%3Abugsites http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://astun-desktop:9080/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"><wfs:member><sf:bugsites gml:id="bugsites.3"><sf:the_geom><gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::26713" srsDimension="2"><gml:pos>590529 4914625</gml:pos></gml:Point></sf:the_geom><sf:cat>3</sf:cat><sf:str1>Beetle site</sf:str1></sf:bugsites></wfs:member></wfs:FeatureCollection>%
```

**Update 24th Oct 2019**

It it is no longer necessary to add the [following jar to GeoServer](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-7343) (at least with versions 2.13.x and later) and it will cause an [error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339660/enabling-cors-in-geoserver-2-15-1-jetty-9-4-12-no-jsp-support-for-did-no). I'm leaving this note here for people fighting older versions.

1. Add the [Jetty-Utility Servlets Jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlets) to match the version of Jetty - for current versions of GeoServer (2.15.x) it is [9.4.12.v20180830](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/9.4.12.v20180830/jetty-servlets-9.4.12.v20180830.jar), copy this to `webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib` inside the geoserver-2.15.0 directory (or wherever you unpacked the zip file).

Comment: For different versions of geoserver, I've been guessing the compatible jetty verison using `find $GEOSERVER_HOME -name "jetty*" | grep -E [[:digit:]]` .

Comment: How do you restart jetty?

Comment: This solution worked for me only after I added [jetty-util](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util) to the `lib` folder as well.

Answer (score 6):

It will work if you add the filter in "geoserver/webapp/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml" and if you add the jar "jetty-servlets.9.2.13.v20150730.jar" inside "geoserver/webapp/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib"

Comment: From where would I get the jetty-servlets.9.2.13.v20150730.jar? Is that different to the jetty-servlet-9.2.13.v20150730.jar which is packaged with Geoserver 2.9?

Comment: yes its different. Also note the destination folder is different

Comment: I am using geoserver 2.8.2.Jetty version not getting.Can any tell me how to find jetty version.I am seeing only jetty-6.8.1 in C:/Program Files (x86)/GeoServer 2.8.2/lib

Answer (score 3):

with Jetty9, UbuntuServer 16.04, i also had to modify /etc/jetty9/start.ini, so as not to get the following error :

```
2018-03-31 15:10:01.769:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED cross-origin: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter
```

the solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608961/eclipse-jetty-plugin-cross-origin-support-class-not-found) : you should enable the servlets module in your ${jetty.base}/start.ini

consequently, i replaced :

```
--module=deploy,http,jsp,jstl,websocket,ext,resources
```

by :

```
--module=deploy,http,jsp,jstl,websocket,ext,resources,servlets
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer by Ian Turton is absolutely best here.
Since I'm using Docker manual editing is not the case.
Also I'm not a SED guru, but thanks to structure of web.xml (target strings are unique in document scope), I come up with little snippet:

```
sed -i 's_<!-- <filter>_<filter>_' web.xml
sed -i 's_</filter> -->_</filter>_' web.xml
sed -i 's_<!-- <filter-mapping>_<filter-mapping>_' web.xml
sed -i 's_</filter-mapping> -->_</filter-mapping>_' web.xml
```

Or in Dockerfile:

```
# enable CORS
RUN wget -q http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/9.2.13.v20150730/jetty-servlets-9.2.13.v20150730.jar -P ${GEOSERVER_INSTALL_DIR}/WEB-INF/lib \
 && sed -i 's_<!-- <filter>_<filter>_' ${GEOSERVER_INSTALL_DIR}/WEB-INF/web.xml \
 && sed -i 's_</filter> -->_</filter>_' ${GEOSERVER_INSTALL_DIR}/WEB-INF/web.xml \
 && sed -i 's_<!-- <filter-mapping>_<filter-mapping>_' ${GEOSERVER_INSTALL_DIR}/WEB-INF/web.xml \
 && sed -i 's_</filter-mapping> -->_</filter-mapping>_' ${GEOSERVER_INSTALL_DIR}/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone is wondering which version of jetty you have for your particular geoserver application.

For OSX I simply started geoserver and looked in the log it should show something like:

```
2019-05-10 07:25:13.444:INFO:oejs.Server:startup executor: jetty-9.2.13.v20150730
```

I'm sure it is similar in the tomcat logs when running from a linux server if needed.

Also, it should be visible in the response headers ie:

```
Connection: close
Server: Jetty(9.2.13.v20150730)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Ie, as the accepted answer mentions try using curl command it will present the server version too:

```
curl -v -H "Origin: http://example.com" http://astun-desktop:9080/geoserver/wfs\?service\=WFS\&version\=2.0.0\&request\=GetFeature\&typenames\=sf:bugsites\&filter\=%3Cfes:Filter%20xmlns:fes\=%22http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0%22%3E%3Cfes:ResourceId%20rid\=%22bugsites.3%22/%3E%3C/fes:Filter%3E
```