# OpenGeo Suite 4.8 - service unavailable after enable CORS edits and restart (Jetty)

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite, cors, jetty

I have Open Geo Suite 4.8 installed on a server.  I tried to enable CORS by following the guide given [here](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/sysadmin/cors/index.html). I have the jetty-servlets file in the directory given in the Boundless instructions.

After restarting  OpenGeo Jetty (version 7.6.13), I now get a 503- Service Unavailable message when I try to view the map services in our web app.

Is there another step that I am missing? The steps given in the Boundless page are pretty straighforward.

I already reviewed the answer given to [Enabling CORS in GeoServer (jetty)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210109), but I am still getting a service unavailable error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally found the problem after digging through the error logs

was nothing more than a comment in the web.xml file that had more than two dashes (even though the line was commented out as expected) ..oof, lesson learned...