# Why getting 403 error in geoserver 2.10.2

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs-t

I know this question asked many times (e.g. [OpenLayers 3: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113693) and 
[Enabling CORS in geoserver 2.8.2 or how to use JSONP in geoserver?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230947)) but those all are not solving my issue.

I am working on **WFS_T** .Below is my code

```
    var transactWFS_polygon = function (p, f) {
    switch (p) {
        case 'insert':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f], null, null, formatGML_polygon);
            break;
        case 'update':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [f], null, formatGML_polygon);
            break;
        case 'delete':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, null, [f], formatGML_polygon);
            break;
    }
    s = new XMLSerializer();
    str = s.serializeToString(node);
    alert(str);
    $.ajax('http://xxx:8076/geoserver/xxxx/ows', {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'xml',
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'text/xml',
        data: str
    }).done();
}
```

I am getting 403 forbidden error in Options.How to enable option in geoserver which is running in localhost.

Comment: Where has this question been asked many times?  Can you include a link or two as a head start for any potential answerers interested in helping?  Have you reviewed [these posts](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bgeoserver%5d%20%22403%22)?

Comment: i amalso facing same issue sir

Comment: $.ajax('http://localhost:9999/geoserver/mywork/wfs/ows', {
     service: 'WFS',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'xml',
        processData: true,
        contentType: 'text/xml',
        data: {data:payload}
    }).done(function() {
      alert("gekki hi ");
   console.log("indside done");
        sourceWFS.clear();
    });

Comment: My ajax is having problem, i guess with url . ajax success message is not working

Comment: for its working by changing configuration in geoserver