# How to use Twitter Typeahead with GeoServer WFS?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, json, ajax

I'm trying to configure the [Twitter Typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) library to work with a GeoServer WFS layer, so I can create an auto-complete feature search function.

Typeahead has the Bloodhound suggestion engine, which can work with a remote data source. There's a good working example at http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/bbzt9hcr/ where the `transform` function is used to convert the nested JSON response into an array which is displayed in the Typeahead dropdown.

I believe that it's necessary to use JSONP and a callback function in order to avoid cross-origin issues in GeoServer (please correct me if I'm wrong) so I'm using the following code to achieve this:

`var parameters = {
        format_options: "callback:typeaheadCallback",
        service: "WFS",
        version: "1.0.0",
        request: "GetFeature",
        typeName: "repairernames",
        outputFormat: "text/javascript",
        propertyName: "repairername",
        CQL_FILTER: "repairername like 'QUERY%'"
    }
    var repairers = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      remote: {
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        url: 'http://localhost/geoserver/blah/wfs?' + jQuery.param(parameters),
        transform: function (result) {
            return $.map(result.features, function (feature) {
              return {
                value: feature.properties.repairername
              };
          });
        },
        prepare: function(query, settings) {
          settings.dataType = "jsonp"
          settings.url = settings.url.replace('QUERY', query)
          return settings;
        }
      }
    });
    function typeaheadCallback(json){
        console.log("Typeahead callback response: ", json);
        return json;
    }`

The change compared to the working demo is the new `prepare` function (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34403026/906814)) which tells Bloodhound/Typeahead to use JSONP, and the callback `typeaheadCallback` which is specified in the parameters.

Via the debugger I can see that the request to GeoServer is successfully implemented, and the `console.log` in the `typeaheadCallback` shows that valid values are returned as JSON.

[image]

The problem is that the `transform` function is never called, so the returned JSON object from GeoServer isn't transformed, and therefore isn't sent to the Typeahead dropdown menu, which therefore doesn't display results.

How can I configure Typeahead and Bloodhound to work with a GeoServer WFS layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONP is not enabled by default (there are security concerns related to it), you have to add a variable to the GeoServer startup: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/global.html

As an alternative, you can enable CORS in the web container running GeoServer instead (check the web container specific instructions on how to enable it).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The answer involved a few changes to my code, including [enabling CORS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/212994/3112) on the GeoServer, specifying `outputFormat=application%2Fjson` and manually encoding all of the parameters into the URL, eg `&CQL_FILTER=repairername%20like%20%27QUERY%25%27`

Answer (score 0):

A few years later and I finally got around to writing this up properly - see http://www.stephenlead.com/posts/using-geoserver-as-the-source-for-a-type-ahead

In short, I needed to add the `prepare` and `transform` functions to the Bloodhound engine as shown below:

```
// Initialize the Bloodhound engine
var bloodhoundEngine = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(datum) {
      return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
    },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  limit: 15,
  remote: {
    url: typeaheadBase + '%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY',
    prepare: function(query, settings) {
      // Build the query string in a GeoServer-ready format
      settings.url = typeaheadBase + jQuery.param(typeaheadParams);
      settings.url += "&CQL_FILTER=strToUpperCase(" + nameField + ")%20like%20%27QUERY%25%27";
      settings.url = settings.url.replace('QUERY', query.toUpperCase());
      return settings;
    },
    transform: function(response) {
      // temporarily persist the geometries of the returned states
      geometries = {};
      return $.map(response.features, function(feature) {
        geometries[feature.properties[nameField]] = feature.geometry;

        // Return the state name to the TypeAhead suggestion dropdown
        return (feature.properties[nameField]);
      });
    }
  },
});
bloodhoundEngine.initialize();
```

See the working demo at https://slead.github.io/GeoServer_TypeAhead/