# Enable CORS in Geoserver not working

Tags: geoserver, jetty

I installed GeoServer 2.12.1 on windows 8.1 x64 and I am trying to design a custom "login" form using AngularJS5 with Node.js, but when I make a request to geoserver it rejected by CORS, and get the error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/. (Reason:
>   CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I read several questions here and follow the steps to enable CORS in geoserver by: downloading the matching "Jetty-Utility Servlets" jar file and putting it in the path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.12.1\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib
```

and also I uncomment the filters in the web.xml file and then restart geoserver .. but all that not worked with me.

I don't know what is wrong. As I said above I read several post about the problem but no luck.Like this question: [Enabling CORS in GeoServer (jetty)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/enabling-cors-in-geoserver-jetty)

---

**The Solution**:
I used in my request headers, the `Authorization` header which doesn't allowed by default by `CORS`, so I added it explicitly in the `web.xml` file:

`<init-param>
<param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
<param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization</param-value>
</init-param>`

Comment: How have you installed Geoserver? using Tomcat & a WAR file? or using the jetty version?

Comment: I installed GeoServer from it's website: http://geoserver.org/ and I choosed the stable version. I think it's  jetty version!? I am so beginner in those things so I am not very sure.

Comment: what happens when you do `curl -v -H "Origin: http://example.com" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs\?service\=WFS\&version\=2.0.0\&request\=GetFeature\&typenames\=sf:bugsites\&filter\=%3Cfes:Filter%20xmlns:fes\=%22http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0%22%3E%3Cfes:ResourceId%20rid\=%22bugsites.3%22/%3E%3C/fes:Filter%3E`

Comment: Here is the replay: `Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /geoserver/wfs\?service\=WFS\ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.57.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://example.com
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
< Content-Length: 298
< Server: Jetty(9.2.13.v20150730)`

Comment: `<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /geoserver/wfs\. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>`