# Fail show shape attribute

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, database, geonetwork

When I click on area, GeoNetwork show the next problem: "No matching records found".

[image]

In geoserver, the information if it is shown.
[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: probably a cors issue - see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/enabling-cors-in-geoserver-jetty

Comment: In this issue my problem is not solved.

I use Geoserver 9.0, I did a search in the folder and uses Jetty 9.3.9.v20160517 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlets/9.3.9.v20160517) I don't know what .jar I have to download.

On the other had I Edit the webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml file and Geoserver stopped working.

Some help? thank you very much.

Comment: please move to a recent version of GeoServer like 2.12 or 2.13 and follow the instructions in that question's answer

Comment: I have tested with Geoserver 13 and continues to report the same error.

Comment: it is still a CORs error unless you can show that it is not