# Geoserver won't start after setting up CORS (no jetty installed?)

Tags: geoserver, cors, jetty

I tried to enable CORS by uncommenting the necessary lines in the web.xml file of geoserver. However, I didn't know that I also had to make sure having the correct jetty servlets jar file in my `WEB-INF/lib` folder (as described in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/enabling-cors-in-geoserver-jetty/250433)). As the CORS didn't work I thought I had to restart tomcat, but since I did that I got an error that jetty couldn't be found:

```
Exception starting filter cross-origin java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter
```

Now I tried to find out which jetty version I use to get the correct servlets jar file, but somehow I cannot find any installation of jetty in my geoserver folder. I installed geoserver with the war file and running it on tomcat. And as I understood jetty comes together with geoserver, so it should exists...

What should be my next step now?

EDIT: geoserver version is 2.13.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using tomcat then any reference to jetty is a red herring. Try following these [instructions for tomcat](https://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html).

Comment: Thanks Ian! This solved my issue. I was confused why there would be a reference to jetty in the web.xml file when I use tomcat...