# GeoServer CORS error for EPSG:3857 GeoJSON

Tags: geoserver, geojson, mbtiles, maplibre-gl

We want to add the data we published from GeoServer (original EPSG 4326 but I published as 3857) as a layer to Maplibre as mbtiles and GeoJSON with WMS. While the system in mbtiles format works, the GeoJSON request gives CORS error. We make the requests according to 3875. You can see the sample code and the error request below.

I added the GEOSERVER_CSRF_DISABLED=true feature when I stand up the system with docker. Do we need to add an extra feature for GeoJSON?

Also from the WMTS Tile caching section, I can see the same data (raw 4326 reprojected with 3857) in 3857 with mbtiles but not with GeoJSON. GeoJSONs are created under /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc/ but GeoServer's default OpenLayers screen does not visualise them. I have tried to get GeoJSON 3857 and 4326 for this data, but both ways do not work.

In the broadcast of the same data with raw crs, i.e. broadcast using 4326, I can see the data in the WMTS section with 4326-GeoJSON, but not with EPSG:900913-GeoJSON.

Any idea?

**Working**

```
store.mapID.on('load', () => {
store.mapID.addSource('parceldata', {
    type: 'vector',
    tiles:
        ['http://<geoserver_link>/geoserver/public/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=public:parcelEimsbuttel3857&bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&width=300&height=300&srs=EPSG:3857&format=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile'] 
      });
store.mapID.addLayer({
  id:'parcels',
  source:'parceldata',
  "source-layer":"parcelEimsbuttel3857",
  type:'line',

})
```

**Not working**

```
store.mapID.on('load', () => {
store.mapID.addSource('parceldata', {
    type: 'geojson',
    data:
        'http://<geoserver_link>/geoserver/public/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=public:parcelEimsbuttel3857&bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&width=300&height=300&srs=EPSG:3857&format=application/json;type=geojson' 
      });
store.mapID.addLayer({
  id:'parcels',
  source:'parceldata',
  type:'line',

})  });
```

---

I use https://github.com/kartoza/docker-geoserver env for setting up my geoserver. It use tomcat so I need to use below web.xml file. I need to attach my volume to /settings and re-build my service. This web.xml file going to change **/tomcat/conf/web.xml** file. Rebuild container seems working and **/tomcat/conf/web.xml** same as below but we are still geting cors error for geojson request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
    <display-name>GeoServer</display-name>
  
      <context-param>
    <param-name>serviceStrategy</param-name>
    <!-- Meaning of the different values :
         
         PARTIAL-BUFFER2
         - Partially buffers the first xKb to disk. Once that has buffered, the the 
           result is streamed to the user. This will allow for most errors to be caught
           early. 
           
         BUFFER
         - stores the entire response in memory first, before sending it off to
           the user (may run out of memory)

         SPEED
         - outputs directly to the response (and cannot recover in the case of an
           error)

         FILE
         - outputs to the local filesystem first, before sending it off to the user
      -->
    <param-value>PARTIAL-BUFFER2</param-value>
  </context-param>
  
  <context-param>
    <!-- see comments on the PARTIAL-BUFFER strategy -->
    <!-- this sets the size of the buffer.  default is "50" = 50kb -->

    <param-name>PARTIAL_BUFFER_STRATEGY_SIZE</param-name>
    <param-value>50</param-value>
  </context-param>
  
  <!--Can be true or false (defaults to: false). -->
  <!--When true the JSONP (text/javascript) output format is enabled -->
  <!--
  <context-param>
    <param-name>ENABLE_JSONP</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  -->
    <!-- 
    <context-param>
      <param-name>PROXY_BASE_URL</param-name>
      <param-value>http://82.58.146.45/geoserver</param-value>
    </context-param>
     -->
   
     <!--
    <context-param>
       <param-name>GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR</param-name>
        <param-value>C:\eclipse\workspace\geoserver_trunk\cite\confCiteWFSPostGIS</param-value>
    </context-param> 
   -->
    
    <!-- pick up all spring application contexts -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:/applicationContext.xml classpath*:/applicationSecurityContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
     <filter-name>FlushSafeFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
     
    <filter>
      <filter-name>Set Character Encoding</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter>
     <filter-name>SessionDebugger</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>     
     <filter-class> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
      <filter-name>xFrameOptionsFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

   <filter>
     <filter-name>GZIP Compression Filter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
         <!-- The compressed-types parameter is a comma-separated list of regular expressions.
              If a mime type matches any of the regular expressions then it will be compressed.
              -->
         <param-name>compressed-types</param-name>
         <param-value>text/.*,.*xml.*,application/json,application/x-javascript</param-value>
     </init-param>
   </filter>
   
   <filter>
     <filter-name>Advanced Dispatch Filter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter</filter-class>
     <!-- 
     This filter allows for a single mapping to the spring dispatcher. However using /* as a mapping
     in a servlet mapping causes the servlet path to be "/" of the request. This causes problems with
     library like wicket and restlet. So this filter fakes the servlet path by assuming the first 
     component of the path is the mapped path. 
     -->
   </filter>
   
   <filter>
    <filter-name>Spring Delegating Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter</filter-class>
    <!--
    This filter allows for filters to be loaded via spring rather than 
    registered here in web.xml.  One thing to note is that for such filters 
    init() is not called. INstead any initialization is performed via spring 
    ioc.
    -->
   </filter>
   
   <filter>
     <filter-name>Thread locals cleanup filter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter</filter-class>
     <!-- 
     This filter cleans up thread locals Geotools is setting up for concurrency and performance
     reasons 
     -->
   </filter>

   <!-- Uncomment following filter to enable CORS in Jetty. Do not forget the second config block further down.
    <filter>
      <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>chainPreflight</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>
    -->
    
    <filter>
      <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>

    <!-- 
      THIS FILTER MAPPING MUST BE THE FIRST ONE, otherwise we end up with ruined chars in the input from the GUI
      See the "Note" in the Tomcat character encoding guide:
      http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding
    -->
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Set Character Encoding</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
   
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
   
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>FlushSafeFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>SessionDebugger</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>GZIP Compression Filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>xFrameOptionsFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
   
    <!-- 
      If you want to use your security system comment out this one too
    -->
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Advanced Dispatch Filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Spring Delegating Filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Thread locals cleanup filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
    <!-- general initializer, should be first thing to execute -->
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <!-- logging initializer, should execute before spring context startup -->
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.geoserver.logging.LoggingStartupContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
  
    <!--  spring context loader -->
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <!--  http session listener proxy -->
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerHttpSessionListenerProxy</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- request context listener for session-scoped beans -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <!-- spring dispatcher servlet, dispatches all incoming requests -->
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    
    <!-- single mapping to spring, this only works properly if the advanced dispatch filter is 
         active -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <mime-mapping>
      <extension>xsl</extension>
      <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
      <extension>sld</extension>
      <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
      <extension>json</extension>
      <mime-type>application/json</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
  
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    
</web-app>
```

Comment: CSRF is completely different to CORS - see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293389/geoserver-wont-start-after-setting-up-cors-no-jetty-installed

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton. I found method from your answer but It's not working. I try to solve