# Display WMS layer from local GeoServer in mobile application with Cesium JavaScript Library?

Tags: geoserver, wms, android, cesium, mobile

I need to display a WMS layer from my local GeoServer in a mobile application with the Cesium JavaScript Library, but I don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

See the [Cesium Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=bVHRSsMwFP2VS582GMl8G7Ubyh5E2FCouJe8ZMm1DaZJSdKOKf67SStY5/IQuOeec+7JTc8d9ApP6GANBk+wRa+6hrwO2IxlYqi31gSuDDqWzW+ZYYZSuJcSOBz2JaiGV+jOoPk5MkwfPX+gXUJ8tB5nkD9wNPpTEy7l4wg8O9srmQIYmMY64HHP2xJdrwRecj8TGaBzOgeW1SG0OaXaCq5r60O+Wq6WtELroxodPTWeZYtRMgT3SRVs2+Y+8IC/3aC0MlUpamwwn6Z5QFs53tZKvEwos3mSfcU7rQqyRVb4cNa4Gd0A7lTTWhdS0BkhNGDT6jSQHjvxjoEI7wdlPAWdSgupelByfeVXQGjufey8dVqX6gNZtilo5P+TastlzPoUdxCfnWj1zWY3goSQgsbyujJYq4/cXTh/Aw)  for an example of how to display GeoServer maps in Cesium.

Also note **you will have to enable CORS on GeoServer**.  Search in GEOSERVER\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\web.xml for CORS and un-comment all CORS sections then restart GeoServer. See this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/enabling-cors-in-geoserver-jetty) or the [GeoServer Manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html#enable-cors).

Comment: Thanks your answer. I checked CORS sections, its ok. I already display wms layer from geoserver in web browser. But I can't it in android application. I show only cesium globe but not geoserver map.

Comment: Did you try it in Cesium Sandcastle?  It has to work there before it has a chance working in your Android app.  Use Cesium Sandcastle and the dev tools in either Firefox or Chrome to debug your tile requests.  Let me know and I will continue to try to help.

Comment: Yes I did, code works (without any error or warning) in cesium sandcastle and chrome.  But I get only this warning in Mozilla Firefox console. "WebGL warning: generateMipmap: Tex image TEXTURE_2D level 0 is incurring lazy initialization.". I show map from geoserver in chrome, cesium sandcastle, firefox. I displayed only cesium default map in android app.