# How to set GeoServer as source in Cesium for Unreal

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, kml, cesium

In GeoServer, I've created a workspace, store, and layer so that I can see the layer preview of the map imagery I want to serve to Cesium for Unreal. Over in Unreal Engine, I have a Cesium3DTileset with Source set to "From URL".

My problem now is figuring out what to enter in the Url field. I'm not seeing any documentation for this. I've tried the link addresses for both OpenLayers and KML, as well as other URLS. But no matter what I enter, Unreal crashes immediately while trying to load the imagery. What URL needs to go there?

[image: URL field in Unreal]

UE crash log:

```
Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x0000000000000000

UE4Editor_CesiumRuntime!Cesium3DTilesSelection::Tileset::LoadTilesetDotJson::start()
UE4Editor_CesiumRuntime!Cesium3DTilesSelection::Tile::getChildren()
UE4Editor_CesiumRuntime!CesiumAsync::Impl::ImmediateScheduler<CesiumAsync::Impl::TaskScheduler>::SchedulerScope::~SchedulerScope()
UE4Editor_Core!TGraphTask<FAsyncGraphTask>::ExecuteTask() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Async\TaskGraphInterfaces.h:886]
UE4Editor_Core!FTaskThreadAnyThread::ProcessTasks() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Async\TaskGraph.cpp:1065]
UE4Editor_Core!FTaskThreadAnyThread::ProcessTasksUntilQuit() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Async\TaskGraph.cpp:888]
UE4Editor_Core!FTaskThreadAnyThread::Run() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Async\TaskGraph.cpp:965]
UE4Editor_Core!FRunnableThreadWin::Run() [D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Windows\WindowsRunnableThread.cpp:86]
```

Comment: Possible CORS issue https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/362660/276

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that GeoServer can provide data in the Cesium3DTileset format, unless you have some custom code to generate it (i.e. an extension to GeoServer that I've not seen discussed in public).

In Cesium, you can do WMS or WMTS, or XYZ tiles. It is claimed to work in Cesium for Unreal, as discussed at https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium-unreal/issues/292 and https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium-unreal/pull/799, but looks like it would take some code (those links describe "adding a `CesiumWebMapServiceRasterOverlay` component to the `CesiumWorldTerrain` Actor".)