# Allow CORS on GeoServer with Tomcat and Nginx

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, cors, nginx

I've used [this procedure](https://gist.github.com/MaxDragonheart/00a90b48100f8ef4f8c452a79bf9000c) for install GeoServer on a server based on Ubuntu 20.04 with Tomcat and Nginx. At the end I've putted under HTTPS my subdomain.

I can see without problems the WMS services and infact I've created [this map](https://massimilianomoraca.it/mappe/webgis/ndvi-analysis/) that use eight WMS link.

The problem comes when I try to pick up the informations from the pixels because I see into console log many problems about CORS origin.

So, I've followed [this procedure](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/container.html#enable-cors) to activate CORS on GeoServer. After the edit of `web.xml` I've reloaded GeoServer clicked on *Reload* into web user interface but GeoServer goes offline with the error:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
> for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.37

I've restarted Tomcat and Nginx with:

```
systemctl restart tomcat
systemctl restart nginx
```

and now I see another error:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message The requested resource [/geoserver/] is not available
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
> for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.37

How I can solve this problem?

**EDIT 1:**

Inside the logs (geoserver/data/logs) there aren't indication about the problem. If I comment again the rows edited inside `web.xml` and use `systemctl restart tomcat` it is possible to use again GeoServer.

**EIDT 2:**

Inside `web.xml` I've this rows that are commented:

```
   <!-- Uncomment following filter to enable CORS
<filter>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>chainPreflight</param-name>
           <param-value>false</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
           <param-value>*</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
           <param-value>GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
           <param-value>*</param-value>
       </init-param>
    </filter>
-->
.
.
.
   <!-- Uncomment following filter to enable CORS
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
-->
```

I uncomment the rows and then save the file.

Comment: Please look in the log files and add any relevant error messages to your question using the [edit] button

Comment: Where I can find the log files? Inside the GeoServer folder I see only `META-INF  WEB-INF  data  index.html`

Comment: look in data/log if it isn't there then then tomcat is failing before GeoServer starts

Comment: @IanTurton I've edited my question

Comment: in which case we need to see exactly what you added to the web.xml file

Comment: Ok @IanTurton I've added the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be following the [instructions for a jetty install](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/enabling-cors-in-geoserver-jetty) rather than the [ones for tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363192/cors-tomcat-geoserver) with the result that tomcat is trying to process a Jetty jar and (understandably) crashes.