# Resolve CORS policy error while fetching layer name from GeoServer using AJAX

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, jquery, ajax

I want to fetch all the layer names from GeoServer using AJAX and append the data in the HTML dropdown. I used xampp server and file in .php extension, Here is my code :

**HTML code** :

```
<label for="layer">Select Layer</label>
<select class="form-control" id="layer" name="layer">
<option value="">Select Layer</option>
</select>
```

**Jquery code** :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
    
            type: "GET",
    
            url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=getCapabilities",
    
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
      
                var select = $('#layer');
                $(xml).find('FeatureType').each(function(){
                    
                    var name = $(this).find('Name').text();
                    
                        $(this).find('Name').each(function(){
                        var value = $(this).text();
                        select.append("<option class='ddindent' value='"+ value +"'>"+value+"</option>");
                    });
                });
                
            }
        });
    });
```

but it gives the below error in the console window :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=getCapabilities' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: turn cors on in Jetty or tomcat (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/enabling-cors-in-geoserver-jetty)

Comment: but I am using xampp server and I used PHP code then what is the solution.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872760/how-do-i-enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-xampp

Comment: I wrote the code: Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization"  but it gives the same error.