GeoServer layer has been blocked by CORS policy
I have a site example.ru on a remote server with ip 90.156.XXX.XX, it runs on https.
I installed GeoServer on this remote machine and ran it on 90.156.XXX.XX:8080, i.e. http://90.156.XXX.XX:8080/geoserver/
When I was trying to get data from the http-link, I got the following error: Mixed Content. The page at was loaded over HTTPS but requested an insecure resource. This request has been blocked the content must be served over HTTPS.
I solved it the way described here: https://dev.to/iamtekson/using-nginx-to-put-geoserver-https-4204
I now have GeoServer responding to https://example.ru/geoserver/ which is the same as https://90.156.XXX.XX/geoserver/
And if I type in a browser line, for example, https://90.156.XXX.XX/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYER=push_how_old:buildings_pushkino_how_old_wmts&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:900913:12&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:900913&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL=2478&TILEROW=1275, I get the file
But the site itself with the code
map.addSource("buildings_pushkino_how_old", {
          type: "vector",
          tiles: [
            "https://90.156.XXX.XX/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYER=push_how_old:buildings_pushkino_how_old_wmts&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:900913:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:900913&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL={x}&TILEROW={y}",
          ],
          bounds: [37.78089132, 55.96388819, 37.93968874, 56.060285621],
        });

gives out errors of the kind:
Access to fetch at 'https://90.156.XXX.XX/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYER=push_how_old:buildings_pushkino_how_old_wmts&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:900913:12&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:900913&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL=2478&TILEROW=1275' from origin 'https://example.ru' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
This is what the nginx config of my site looks like:
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name example.ru www.example.ru;
return 301 https://example.ru$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
server_name www.example.ru;
return 301 https://example.ru$request_uri;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example/example.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example/example.key;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
server_name example.ru;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example/example.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example/example.key;
root /var/www/example;
index index.html;

add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '<https://example.ru>' always;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /geoserver {
        proxy_pass <http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver>;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }

In the Geoserver web.xml file, I removed the comments from these lines:
       <filter>
       <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
       <init-param>
         <param-name>chainPreflight</param-name>
         <param-value>false</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
         <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
         <param-value>*</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
         <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
         <param-value>GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
         <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
         <param-value>*</param-value>
       </init-param>
     </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Set Character Encoding</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

And still the error remains. Can you please tell me what else I can do or where I made a mistake?

Did you make any cors settings?

@IanTurton, Only the ones I described in the question

Are you running tomcat?

@IanTurton , no

Then those changes will make no difference,

@IanTurton, can I use Tomcat with Nginx or should I switch to Apache?

You could follow the instructions for jetty instead

@IanTurton, Didn't I do this when I uncommented the code in web.xml?

See https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/210109/79

I figured out what the cause was
After transferring GeoServer  from http://90.156.XXX.XX:8080/geoserver/  to https://90.156.XXX.XX/geoserver/, which is the same as https://example.ru/geoserver/  when connecting the layer
map.addSource("buildings_pushkino_how_old", {
          type: "vector",
          tiles: [
            "https://90.156.XXX.XX/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYER=push_how_old:buildings_pushkino_how_old_wmts&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:900913:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:900913&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL={x}&TILEROW={y}",
          ],
          bounds: [37.78089132, 55.96388819, 37.93968874, 56.060285621],
        });

instead of https://90.156.XXX.XX/geoserver/ should have specified https://example.ru/geoserver/ and CORS changes in web.xml were not needed in this case.
